# Как вставить под категорию в базу данных Sql

Tags: php, android, mysql

У меня программа сейчас работает так:

> Category < Menu < Menu_detal.

Как мне правильно прописать в базе данных для того, чтобы было вот так:

> Category1 < Category < Menu < Menu_detal?

Table structure `tbl_category`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_category` (
  `Category_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Category_image` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Category_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить поле category_parent, со значением родительской категории, или 0, если это соло элем. Дальше просто: если у элем 1 есть родитель, то сначала отрисовать его, и так рекурсивно сколько нужно

```
    /*
     * Итак, я исхожу из того, что нужно вывести примерно вот такое меню
     *
     *
     * Средства передвижения
     * Автомобиль
     * Легковой
     * Седан
     * Dodge
     *
     * Если да, то всё очень просто:
     *
     * 1) в SQL добавляем поле category_parent, со значением id родителя, или 0, если это конец
     *
     * Дальше, всё что нужно, в текущей странице получить id последней категории
     * (допустим, что Dodge => id=176)
     *
     * 2) пишем внешний вид
     * */




    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @param int $currentCatId => id последней категории, от которой будем плясать
     * @return string
     *
     * Что должно быть в data
     * $data = [
                0 => [
                'id'    => 18,
                'title' => "Грузовые",
                'category_parent'   => 12,
                # .........
                ],
                1 => [
                'id'    => 19,
                'title' => "Легковушки",
                'category_parent'   => 12,
                # .........
                ],
                # ..........
    ];
     *
     */

    # переведу массив выше так, чтобы ключ записи соответствовал id
    $t = [];
    foreach ($data as $k => $d){
            $t[$d['id']]=$d;
    }
    function echoHtml($data,$currentCatId):string
    {
            $result = '';
            $result.= $data[$currentCatId]['title'];
            if($data[$currentCatId]['category_parent']!=0){
                $result.=echoHtml($data,$data[$currentCatId]['category_parent']);
            }
            else{
                $result.= $data[$currentCatId]['title'];
            }


            return $result;
    }
   echo echoHtml($t,12345);
```

Это наброски, главная задача, как я и описал - рекурсивно перебрать записи. Всё что нужно, проверить всё это на реальных данных, и мб поправить что-нужно в моей ф-и

Comment: Alex Khonko не могли бы вы помочь мне и дописать таблицу базы и методы вывода ... Разумеется за финансовое вознаграждение.... Мой email shihnazarov@mail.ru... напишите мне...

Comment: @Ильхам дописал свой ответ. Если всё равно не понятно, то уже только завтра(своих задач на работе хватает)

Comment: Примерно у меня должно получится так : Рестораны( Весна , Салам, Арена) клик по иконки (Весна) в Ресторанах. Открывается под категория ресторана (Весна)< (Шашлыки ,Салаты ,Горячее ) и т.д...